# How to reverse everything after the second line with AWK

Tags: bash, awk

I'm looking for a way to ignore the first two lines of a file, and flip the ips/dns' of everything after the second line. Please note that I `sed remove` first line (which is a header).

```
bash-4.4$ less test
  1 #remove
  2 #comment 1
  3 #comment 2
  4 foo 127.0.0.1
  5 bar 127.0.0.1
```

the results I am looking for are

```
bash-4.4$ less test-fixed
  1 #comment 1
  2 #comment 2
  3 127.0.0.1 foo
  4 127.0.0.1 bar
```

the command pipe I've been trying is:

```
FILE=/tmp/test ; sed '1d' $FILE | awk 'NR>2 { t = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = t; print; } ' >| /tmp/test-fixed
```

obviously `NR>2` ordinal number of the current record and skips to line 3 so I'm thinking I need an iteration loop to print them but not operate until `N3` is reached? Not sure...

Comment: You never need sed when you're using awk since awk can do anything useful that sed can do. `sed '1d'` = `awk 'NR>1'` or `awk 'NR==1{next}'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk 'NR>3{s=$NF; $NF = $(NF-1); $(NF-1) = s} 1' file

1 #remove
2 #comment 1
3 #comment 2
4 127.0.0.1 foo
5 127.0.0.1 bar
```

Comment: Can't accept yet, but nice one. Because of the `sed` statement the `awk` needs to be rejiggered, but this is a working answer. thanks @anubhava

Comment: `sed '1d' $FILE | awk 'NR>2{s=$NF; $NF = $(NF-1); $(NF-1) = s} 1'` fixed for you

Comment: Won't that delete `1 #remove` line from output though you have shown it in your expected output.

Comment: correct which is the expected, updating the question since I didn't declare that appropriately

Comment: ok then probably you can avoid `sed` by using `awk 'NR==1{next} NR>3{s=$NF; $NF = $(NF-1); $(NF-1) = s} 1' file`

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 'NR > 1 && NR <= 3; NR > 3 {print $2, $1}' input.txt
```

**Output**

```
#comment 1
#comment 2
127.0.0.1 foo
127.0.0.1 bar
```

Comment: like the use of the inclusive switch, plus one to you sir

Answer (score 2):

with line numbers

```
$ awk 'NR==1 {next} 
       NR>3  {t=$3; $3=$2; $2=t} 
             {print NR-1,$2,$3}' file

1 #comment 1
2 #comment 2
3 127.0.0.1 foo
4 127.0.0.1 bar
```

or golfed version

```
$ awk 'NR>3{t=$3;$3=$2;$2=t} --$1' file
```

Comment: plus one for providing a code golf, lol. it's extremely elegant and displaying how you can add multiple executions inside of a single awk statement.